# WebStorm "Track Changes" setting does not work with custom TypeScript compiler

Tags: typescript, webstorm

When setting in WebStorm custom TypeScript version (for example 2.5.2) then option "Track Changes" under "Enable TypeScript Compiler" stop working, it works only with the WebStorm bundled TypeScript Compiler. Basically when you create a *.ts file it is no longer compiled automatically as it is the case when you use the bundled inside WebStorm TypeScript compiler.

Can someone confirm that this is the case or "Track Changes" should work with any TypeScript version ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a WebStorm bug: [WEB-28374](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28374)

Workarounds:

1. Add the `"compileOnSave":true` option to the `tsconfig.json`
2. Use WebStorm version >= 2017.2.3

Comment: Looks like it's still a bug, I'm using 2018,1 here and it only works with the embedded typescript compiler...